# What does T& mean for some template argument T?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, reference, type-traits

For example

```
template<class T>
struct Ref
{
    using type = T&;
};
```

Is `Ref<T>::type` the same as `std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type` for all possible template arguments? E.g. `int`, `int&`, and `int&&`?

I just read the source code for `std::add_lvalue_reference<T>`. Quite sure they are equivalent.
 If they are, we can save some space by simply writing `T&` instead.

Comment: @cdhowie Wow, didn't even know about that question. The answers seem somewhat similar...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Table 53 in [meta.trans.ref] - definition of `add_lvalue_reference`:

> If `T` names an object or function type then the member typedef type
>   shall name `T&`; otherwise, if `T` names a type “rvalue reference to
>   `T1`” then the member typedef type shall name `T1&`; otherwise, type
>   shall name `T`.

Now recall the rules for reference collapsing:

> If […] a type *template-parameter* (14.3.1) […] denotes a type `TR` that
>   is a reference to a type `T`, **an attempt to create the type “lvalue
>   reference to *cv* `TR`” creates the type “lvalue reference to `T`”** […]

So the answer is yes:

- For objects or functions the condition is trivially met. It's just `T&`, no reference collapsing involved.
- For rvalue references, an lvalue reference to the type referred-to, `T1`, is created.
- For lvalue references the exact reference type is preserved.